# Lexical or Preprocessor build issues Xcode 10 Swift 4

Tags: swift, xcode, interface-builder

I'm having a bunch of odd build issues in Xcode. This keeps popping up.

[image]

I cleaned the build folder and ran the app again. I got this stack of errors:

[image]

I also tried updating my pods, but nothing changed.

Last time this happened, I removed all pods from the project and re-installed them. It fixed the issue for a while.